# How can I automate window arrangement?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I know and have been reading a few ideas about how to "import" the features of xmonad/tiling window managers in OSX. I don't care much about the X11/Xquartz windows, but about conventional OSX windows.

Now, all the solutions I have seen around lack the one feature I'd really like to have: not to worry about windows anymore.

Let me explain:

I'd like to have a system (as in xmonad on linux) in which I have 2/3 different modes (in xmonad I'd use Simplest, TwoPanes and Grid) and windows (newly created or existing) *automagically* adhere to the layout I have selected: no mouse involved, no keys to be pressed. Then I'd need a keyboard shortcut to be able to switch from one mode to another.

Obviously a big plus would be to be able to handle exceptions (as in xmonad, floating windows) or a keyboard shortcut to move around a window freely.

Comment: This would be great! I too use XMonad with Linux and wish it could be ported fully to OSX

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/). It lets you save window configurations (position and size) in profiles. Unfortunately, these profiles only deal (multi) display arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

[Slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) is an OS X window manager "application" that looks promising. Its stock configuration isn't that great, but it is extremely configurable. Also, it uses the OS X "Accessibility" API, so it doesn't require admin privileges to install. That is pretty clever.

Answer (score 0):

Well. There is no such Window manager on Mac OS X. If you want one, you'll have to write it. The standard API won't allow you to do everything you mentioned. You'll have to dig a little and use some private APIs.

Here's an old (2005) open-source project that might help you:
http://developer.berlios.de/project/showfiles.php?group_id=3463